# Create azure secret with get-Credetials in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, cloud, azure-keyvault

I am trying to automate VM creation in azure.
I want to prompt users to fill in credentials and then store them in my azure key vault as a secret. the problem is it automatically transfers the password to a secure string thus I can't store the value...

Comment: `[System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new([string]::Empty,$passw).Password` or `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode($passw))` or `ConvertFrom-SecureString $passw -AsPlainText` if you have PS Core. A simple google search would have yielded the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In fact Azure expects you to pass a SecureString to the KeyVault with **Set-AzKeyVaultSecret**. So you don't need to convert it to plain text.

[Set-AzKeyVaultSecret in Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/set-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-6.5.0)

```
# Read in Credentials (Password will be of type SecureString)
$Credential = Get-Credential
     
# Save password in your key vault
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -Name "MySecret" -VaultName "MyKeyVaultName" -SecretValue $Credential.Password
```

[image]

---

And to make it more complete. Here's how you can retrieve it as plain text.

```
# Plain password
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```